# How to deploy using Hostinger?

Tags: deployment, web-hosting

I got an assignment to create a simple app and to deploy it in a website.

During development I was using xampp and never had an issue.

I do not know how to format folder directories but here I go. I have `index` and `libs` (folder) at same hierarchy, inside `libs` I have 3 folders, for `css`, `js` and `php`.

One file inside `css`, jQuery and scripts inside `js` and 3 files calling different apis inside `php`.

My first time hosting a website so I youtubed how to do it. however, I cannot get it to work properly.

I get the following error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

and it points to my jQuery and js file.

I have tried every "solution" available but nothing has been improved.
If anyone knows what is causing this can you please let me know or point towards some documentation so that I can fix it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue.
The folder inside were in upper case and it causes an issue because the path was case sensitive.
By changing the path to JS instead of js and PHP opose to php, it was able to find the file